# How to get UTF-8 conversion for a string

Tags: java

`Frédéric`  in java converted to `FrÃ©dÃ©ric`.
However i need to pass the proper string to my client.
How to achieve this in Java ?

Did tried

```
String a = "FrÃ©dÃ©ric";
String b = new String(a.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

However string b also contain same value as a.
I am expecting string should able to store value as : `Frédéric`
How to pass this value properly to client.

Comment: How do you pass the `String` to your client? What is the client written in and how is it processing your `String`?

Comment: Java strings are internally utf-16, and any `String` you create will be in that format. You can get the corresponding utf-8 bytevector like `"Frédéric".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` if that's what you want.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the numerous other questions about decoding input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking for a function that will repair strings that have been damaged by others' encoding mistakes?

Here's one that seems to work on the example you gave:

```
static String fix(String badInput) {
    byte[] bytes = badInput.getBytes(Charset.forName("cp1252"));
    return new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}

fix("FrÃ©dÃ©ric") == "Frédéric"
```

Comment: static String fix(String badInput) {
    byte[] bytes = badInput.getBytes(Charset.forName("cp1252"));
    return new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}

fix("FrÃ©dÃ©ric") == "Frédéric"

Answer (score 0):

Find your language code **[here](http://webtools.live2support.com/misc_htmlcharset.php)** and use that.

> String a = new String(yourString.getBytes(), YOUR_ENCODING);

You can also try:

> String a = URLEncoder.encode(yourString, HTTP.YOUR_ENCODING);

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite complicated. See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html for basic understanding. 
My first suggestion would be to save your Java file with utf-8. Default for Eclipse on Windows would be cp1252 which might be your problem. Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If `System.out.println("Frédéric")` shows the garbled output on the console it is most likely that the encodings used in your sourcecode (seems to be UTF-8) is not the same as the one used by the compiler - which by default is the platform-encoding, so probably some flavor of ISO-8859. Try using `javac -encoding UTF-8` to compile your source (or set the appropriate property of your build environment) and you should be OK.

If you are sending this to some other piece of client software it's most likely an encoding issue on the client-side.